# Custom webcomponent from library in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-component

I have a React application which should use the following library:
[MICO-grapheditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ustutt/grapheditor-webcomponent)

And I want to write this code:

```
render() {
    var webgraph = require("@ustutt/grapheditor-webcomponent");
    GraphEditor.
    return (
        <network-graph classes="red blue" mode="layout" zoom="both">
            <style slot="style">
                svg {width:100%; height: 100%}
            </style>
            <svg slot="graph"></svg>
        </network-graph>
    )
}}
```

But I get the following:

> TS2339: Property 'network-graph' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

At least the expression

```
var webgraph = require("@ustutt/grapheditor-webcomponent");
```

should come up before the rendering. Also, doing CSS in HTML and Node.js/React is not pretty much the same. Or is it?

Comment: ohh yes 
I added the line to test if it would work but honestly I have more ore less no clue in JS/TS

Answer (score 0):

React is likely assuming that *network-graph* is a React component, thus it expects that the attributes you are using (`mode` and `zoom`) are defined in a React component. Also React uses `className` instead of `classes`.

When you write between `<network-graph>` tags this content is considered as a group of child nodes that can be used by the *network-graph* component in the following way:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class NetworkGraph extends Component {
  render() {
    const {mode, zoom, children} = this.props;
    return (
      <>{children}</>
    ); // children would contain the <svg>
  }
}
```

When you *require* MICO-grapheditor, you are not importing a React component, but a web component instead, even though React tries to interpret it...

Also, avoid shoving in `<style>` tags in the render's return. CSS styles in React may be imported to components like  so `import './my-styles.css';`.

Comment: I don't really understand how Typescript knows now to connect the created NetworkGraph with the network-graph tag from the script. Also do I get an error for the mode and zoom in the probs

Comment: @paulesn Grapheditor's `network-graph` is a 3rd-party Web-component (i.e. not a React component), thus it isn't understood when [its code](https://mico-grapheditor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) is used in React's JSX code. From [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html): "using third-party Web Components, the best solution is to write a React component that behaves as a wrapper for your Web Component." => You can start developing the support from this basis, more people might be interested if you develop and publish this specific wrapper in Github.